# How to create complete Laravel rest api and and confusing with Laravel REST controller

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

I am very new to Laravel, and now I am on my first Laravel project. Now I need to provide REST api for mobile. I followed REST resource controller documentation on Laravel website. But when I call my REST api, it is not returning any value.

How to complete rest api in Laravel? I am using Laravel 5.

My REST API server code follows.

*"route"*

```
Route::resource('/users','user_accessController');
```

*"controller"*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;

class user_accessController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return Response::json(array('name'=>'wai yan'));
    }
}
```

Client code:

*"using curl"*

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'http://laravel.bbc:8080/users');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);

    $res = curl_close($ch);
```

What is wrong with my code? It is not returning any value.

Comment: Try using the full namespae for the route Route::resource('/users','App\Http\Controllers\user_accessController');

Comment: BTW: you should be following naming convention. See how classes are named in Laravel. No class is named like yours.

Comment: I already followed convention . Same result .

Comment: what happens when you visit this URL from your browser? `http://laravel.bbc:8080/users`

Comment: It is returning this . {"name":"Wai Yan"}

Comment: that means its working. check your cURL commands, have you echoed `$res` and see what it holds?

Comment: try `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://laravel.bbc:8080/users` using command line just to checking

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to understand Laravel's naming convention.

StudlyCase for your controllers.

Use artisan command to generate resource controller

```
php artisan make:controller UserAccessController
```

Your route:

```
Route::resource('/users','UserAccessController');
```

"controller" - file name: `UserAccessController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Response;
//use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; no need for this both files are in same namespace

use App\User;

class UserAccessController extends Controller {

    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(['name' => 'wai yan']);
    }


}
```

Am using Laravel 5 with same code above and this is the output when I used curl command:

`curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://laravel.dev/users`

[image]

Comment: I added this line in php  .  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'));  . But it is not working .

Comment: are you running this code from same laravel project?

Comment: No . I am running from different project . So to consume it from different project , what should I do please ?

Comment: If the different project is using PHP I do suggest you use GuzzleHttp for making requests as its has so many nice methods. http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ example you can do this: `$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get('http://laravel.dev/users'); $json = $response->json();` The `echo $json['name'] ` \\prints Wai yan

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestion . I got the chance to know the new thing . But how can I access using Curl ? Any idea please ?

Comment: This guzzle was very helpful to me . But I am still looking for a solution for Curl cos my teammates using curl . Thank you so much .

Comment: same way... to get started var_dump( $res) to see what it contains then you will know how to consume the response, maybe by using array keys e.g  echo $res['name'] or If your API returns json you can use echo json_decode($res); echo "My name is $res['name']";

Comment: I think the issue you are having is not from Lavavel but issue of how to consume API data. See this simple example that uses curl https://support.ladesk.com/061754-How-to-make-REST-calls-in-PHP

Comment: But using CURL is not returning a value . That is the problem .

Comment: what do you see when you `var_dump($res)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$chatToken = "put your API KEY";

header("Content-type: text / html; charset = utf-8");

$option = array (
    "body" => "Test posting Messages"
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/roomid/messages");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($option));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('X-ChatWorkToken:'. $chatToken));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```